# Android Post text to Google plus community

Tags: android, google-plus, android-sharing

I am trying to post some text into community

i seen lot of tutorial to share text to profile

Can some one give me suggestion how i can post text to the Google plus community

I tried like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
             Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(MainActivity.this)
                      .setType("text/plain")
                      .setText(vo)
                      .getIntent()
                      .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus")
                       .setClassName("com.google.android.apps.plus",
                     "com.google.android.apps.plus.phone.UrlGatewayActivity")
            .putExtra("customAppUri", 
              "https://plus.google.com/communities/107139874057758406172");

                   startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
  .setType("text/plain")
  .setText("Heard about this restaurant from +109813896768294978296. Check out the menu +friendnotonplus@example.com")
  .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/examples/restaurant"))
  .getIntent();

startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
```

Reference : https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/prefill